Is it possible to redirect my domain name to github.io repository while keeping my domain URL?
I apologize if the title is a little confusing, since I don't know the exact terminology for redirects.
I own a domain, say, example.com that I manage under Cloudflare. I also have a Github repo, say, foo that is hosted as https://hobbes3.github.io/foo/index.html. However, my website code only works if my index.html is at the root level like https://example.com/index.html. Because the extra foo/ path in the default github.io breaks my code due to JavaScript and image referencing off the root path.
So, is there anyway I can have my repo as subdomains and redirect https://foo.example.com/ to https://hobbes3.github.io/foo/ while preserving my domain name (meaning I don't want the URL to actually change to the github.io path)?
Cloudflare redirects: https://developers.cloudflare.com/rules/url-forwarding/
Then later I can do something like https://bar.example.com/ for my bar repo as well.
Or do I have to rewrite all my website code to hardcode the Github repo name, foo and bar? Or I have to host my own server like Apache or Nginx to perform this kind of redirect?

Is there no option to rewrite all your website code to use relative paths?

@user1686 My code is using relative paths, but I would have to hardcode the repo name in all of my links like foo/image.jpg instead of just image.jpg since the site would be located at hobbes3.github.io/foo/. And that doesn't seem very clean.

How so? If the HTML file is at /my_website/index.html and the image is at /my_website/image.jpg, then the relative path would be just image.jpg, wouldn't it?

@user1686 You're right. I'm dumb. I had all of my path start with a / like /image.jpg (well real issues were paths for my javascript in my require.js, but the same idea). If you post your solution, then I'll go accept it. Thanks!
